# Inconsistent edge data in graph in networkx

Tags: networkx

Using networkx I created a graph G and added the edge (1,2).  Strangely,

```
(1,2) in G.edges() == False
```

but

```
G.has_edge(1,2) == True
```

I'm baffled.  This is a concise summary of the problem.  The actual graph data is large and cannot be reproduced here in full.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `G.edges()` only has each edge once.  Since it's an undirected graph, it could be as either `(1,2)` or as `(2,1)` (you wouldn't want both to appear --- you might be iterating and delete the edge the first time).  You can't be sure of what order it will do so because it's coming from a python dict, which [does not have predictable order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479928/why-is-the-order-in-python-dictionaries-and-sets-arbitrary).  You could do `(1,2) in G.edges() or (2,1) in G.edges()`, but you really don't want to do that - it's inefficient to create the edge lists.

So the test should use `G.has_edge(1,2)` which checks it correctly (and much more efficiently).

---

Just to show the lack of predictability for different python implementations, this is what I get

> In [3]: G=nx.Graph()
>
> In [4]: G.add_edge(1,2)
>
> In [5]: G.edges()
>
> Out[5]: [(1, 2)]
>
> In [6]: (1,2) in G.edges()
>
> Out[6]: True
>
> In [7]: G.add_edge(4,3)
>
> In [8]: G.edges()
>
> Out[8]: [(1, 2), (3, 4)]
>
> In [9]: (4,3) in G.edges()
>
> Out[9]: False